How to maximize the use of the gesture bar height in Android?
I am trying to use the edge to edge in my app. I am using bottom bar in my app. I am trying place the bottom bar as much as posibile.
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(
            findViewById<View>(R.id.bottombar)
        ) { v: View, insets: WindowInsetsCompat ->
            val bars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemGestures())
            v.setPadding(bars.left, 0, bars.right, bars.bottom)
            insets
        }


gesture height is fixed. But I verified in amazon app. In that app gesture height is little low compare with my app.

How to maximize the use of the gesture bar height in Android? Any Idea.

My mistake. Instead of using WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemGestures(), we should be using WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars().
Updated code:
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) {
                view: View, windowInsets: WindowInsetsCompat ->

            val insets =
                windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            view.updatePadding(bottom = insets.bottom)
            windowInsets
        }

